# Simplest way to ship C or Fortran snippets with Python package

Tags: python, c, fortran

I'd like to add a small snippet of high-performance non-Python code to an otherwise pure Python package (maintained by someone else). This snippet only contains a few loops over a larger numpy array with only elementary math operations involved (meaning I don't care whether this part is written in C or Fortran or whatever else). Compared to Numpy this snippet does not allocate hidden temporary memory and speeds things up by 10x - 30x.

I'd like to keep distribution of the package as simple as possible and so I'd like to avoid any additional (heavy) dependencies like Numba or relying on Fortran or C compilers. The last drop of performance is not important.

**Question:** What is the simplest way to include high-performance code snippets into an otherwise pure Python package?

Comment: Have you considered Cython? http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/ It interfaces easily with NumPy arrays. If you want to ship the code, you can build binary wheels for the target platforms. Then, the end-user does not need a compiler.

Comment: Yes, I am away of Cython. Problem with binary wheels is that I'd have to ask the maintainer of the package to provide different binary wheels for different target platforms, which is an overhead I'd like to avoid. Is it possible to pre-compile code for different platforms and to choose the right one at runtime?

Comment: No, you need to build one wheel per platform. Installation via pip then picks the suitable wheel for the user. One intermediate solution is to make the accelerated code optional, depending on whether or not the user has cython + compiler.

Comment: I ended up using Numba and shipping additional python methods as fallback. Thanks for your responses!